# How to exclude directory in coverage for Python multi-module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, coverage.py

I've project whose directory structure looks like below

```
ProjectRoot
    - Module1
        src/
        tests/
    - Module2
        src/
        tests/
    ...
```

From the root directory I want to run all the tests and calculate the coverage. This is the command I'm using

`python -m coverage run --branch -m unittest **/tests/test*`

Here, I want to exclude certain directories. How can I do that?

I tried one approach where I created `.coveragerc` and added modules to excluded in that

```
...
omit =
    Module2/*
...
```

and giving this file to command as 
`python -m coverage run --rcfile=.coveragerc --branch -m unittest **/tests/test*`

But it still tries to pick up the Module2 for tests.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried in my case, eventually this helps, this is my current project (three modules):

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover

include =
    ../toolbox/*.py
    ../geometry_finder/*.py
    ../position_optimiser/*.py

[html]
directory = c:\tmp\Report
```

I now tried the following:

```
[report]
exclude_lines =
    pragma: no cover

include =
    ../.

omit = 
    ../toolbox/*.py

[html]
directory = c:\tmp\Report
```

... and I did not see the coverage of toolbox. Therefore I cannot really confirm. Code was started using:

```
coverage run --branch .\unittest_package.py
coverage html
```

Comment: IMHO, you're giving specific python file as input so there's no question running it on ../toolbox/*.py.

Comment: You mean the actual python command, where I specify the unittest file? True, I collect all tests in one unittest, but this has no influence on the actual coverage functionality. I include everything in my test, and then exclude the toolbox (testwise).

Comment: That's what I don't want to do. If I add the tests and/or modules they should be automatically detected. I cannot keep adding to some additional file.